# Loss of file path added as a link to Visual Studio project in other systems

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two C# projects that I want to use from some first project classes to the second project. I use from Add->Existing Item-> AddAsLink in the second project. it's good, but when I transfer my second project to other systems, files that added as link lost, because file path don't exist in that system.
do you have any solution?

**Note :

 1) I don't want to copy class files to the second project.

 2) I don't want to create Dll file for these classes and add them to the second project**

Comment: a good way to do this would be to package the first project up as a Nuget package, and then install the package into your second project.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use hard links.

You add required hard links from project having the files to the project folder needing links.

Next you add files to the second project as normal. And you're done.

But when you copy projects you need to delete duplicates files that are no more links and recreate hard links on the file system of the new computer, and when you'll open projects you're done.

From command line use mklink.exe:

```
MKLINK /H Link Target
```

Example:

```
mklink /h MirroredFullFileName OriginalFullFileName
```

So it is now like quantum entanglement.

You can create a batch file matching your project to automate the process.

There are some shell integrated GUI tools:

https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+hardlink+shell+extension

https://superuser.com/questions/345746/how-to-copy-files-and-create-hardlinks-instead-of-copying-when-files-are-identic